# pandas: use `DataFrame.fillna` to fill missing values for `DataFrame.add`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The `DataFrame.add(fill_value=my_value)` method allows you to add to data frames, and choose a *single* value `my_value` to be used for replacing missing values.

On the other hand, the `DataFrame.fillna` gives more flexibility on filling missing values (eg, allows you to pad trailing missing values with the last valid one per column), but can be applied only to an already existing dataframe.

Is there any way to use something like the `DataFrame.fillna` to fill missing values during addition of two dataframe when using `DataFrame.add`, instead of a single value??

eg. I would like to perform the equivalent of

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
B = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3], index=['b', 'c', 'd'])
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': A, 'b': B})
frame = frame.fillna(method='pad') # pad trailing missing values with last valid ones, column-wise
frame = frame.fillna(value=0) # pad (remaining) leading values with zeros
result = frame.sum(axis=1)
```

but using `A.add(B, unknown_params)`. If that's not available, is there any other method more efficient that what I'm currently doing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A universal, magic method to perform all your manipulations does not exist. You can create a function, utilize method chaining and use [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to make your code clearer:

```
def fill_sum(df):
    return df.fillna(method='pad').fillna(0).sum(1)

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': A, 'b': B})

frame = frame.pipe(fill_sum)

print(frame)

a    1.0
b    3.0
c    5.0
d    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks. is there a function that allows something similar when adding 2 Series `A + B`, without first creating a dataframe out of them??

Comment: Yep, you can use `A + B` :). This will give a series rather than a dataframe.

Comment: But that doesn't `pad` the missing values :(

Comment: @blue_note, Then there's no magic method / function. You have to create one yourself. Pandas just provides tools, it doesn't provide methods for every combination of tools.